# Extra quote marks in Node JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, string, isomorphic-javascript

I have a module that creates and exports a config object. When running in a browser environment, its string values *must* be JSON.stringified. Otherwise, they are interpreted as bare identifiers.

In node, JSON.stringify seems to add an extraneous set of double quotes.

What solution would work in both browser and node?

Most of the node modules I've checked out, searching for JSON.stringify deal with String representations/translations of complex objects.

### works in browser + webpack 2.2.4, fails in node:

```
module.exports = {
    url: JSON.stringify(process.env.SOME_URL),
    // in node, resolves to '"https://..."'
    headers: {
        Authorization: JSON.stringify(basicAuthString),
        // in node, resolves to '"Basic ...="'
        'Content-Type': JSON.stringify('application/json'),
    }
};
```

### works in node, fails in browser + webpack 2.2.4:

```
module.exports = {
    url: process.env.SOME_URL,
    // in node, resolves to bare https://...
    // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    headers: {
        Authorization: basicAuthString,
        // in browser, resolves to bare Basic ...=
        // actions.js:15 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
        'Content-Type': JSON.stringify('application/json'),
    }
};
```

The `process.env` values, in the case of webpack, are captured at build time, using this approach: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-pass-environment-variables

### Update: Workaround and remaining question

1. What is the **root cause** of the issue?

   - the library code
   - webpack 2x that builds library user projects
   - Babel 6.24.1, used to build the library

This workaround just checks for repeated quotes at beginning and end. It works in both environments.

```
const str = (s) => {
    let ret = JSON.stringify(s);
    if (ret.indexOf('""') === 0) {
      ret = ret.slice(1);
    }
    if (ret[ret.length - 2] === '"') {
      ret = ret.slice(0, -1 + ret.length);
    }
    return ret;
};

module.exports = { foo: str('bar') };
```

Comment: show the value of process.env.SOME_URL, it's weird that you're using JSON.stringify for just an URL.

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting and getting?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande 
    `echo $SOME_URL`
    `https://api.example.com`

Comment: @alpeshpandya it's as indicated in comments. 
Expecting `{"url":"https://api.example.com","headers":{"Authorization":"Basic dGVpMzkSUDFuazE3TMA=","Content-Type":"application/json"})`  

Getting this in node.js:  `{"url":'"https://api.example.com"',"headers":{"Authorization":'"Basic dGVpMzkSUDFuazE3TMA="',"Content-Type":'"application/json"'})`. 

In webpack, getting `{"url":https://api.example.com,"headers":{"Authorization":Basic dGVpMzkSUDFuazE3TMA=,"Content-Type":application/json})`

Comment: Why are you using JSON.stringify at all here? seems rather counterproductive to solving your problem.

Comment: Why don't you use `String(process.env.SOME_URL)` instead?

Comment: everything stored in `process.env` is already a string - no need to do any conversions or stringifying - you'll either get a string back, or `undefined` if you ask for a key that doesnt exist - "Assigning a property on process.env will implicitly convert the value to a string."  - https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env

Comment: I think this explains the "root cause" of your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564802/why-does-webpacks-defineplugin-require-us-to-wrap-everything-in-json-stringify - basically, webpack is the thing that needs you to JSON.stringify it because it uses the values as code fragments inserted verbatim into your code - but in node - you shouldnt be stringifying it

Answer (score 0):

[By definition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3) `JSON.stringify()` converts string into string by adding extra quotes.

> If Type(value) is String, then return the result of calling the abstract operation Quote with argument value.

Instead of `JSON.stringify()` can't you just use `String()`?
Node won't change the string, webpack should handle it properly, too.